# 'Element belongs to different frame' error when switching to frame in Serenity BDD

Tags: selenium, frame, serenity-bdd

I have a test-suite that was using Thycidides/jbehave and it worked fine (although against an older version of FireFox because development switched to Sernity BDD). I have now migrated to the new Serenity BDD (still jbehave) and updated FireFox, but I'm suddenly running into a error when trying to switch to a frame on a specific page/test.

Our site has a LOT of frames, but the frame switching works on all pages/tests expect on a single page/test (which seems to have the same frame structure as the other working tests). When I try to switch to a specific frame (that I know is there) I get a 'Element belongs to a different frame than the current one - switch to its containing frame to use it' (and a link to stale_element_reference) (SerenityManagedException.detachedCopyOf) which doesn't make much sense at that's what I'm trying to do. I wrote some alternative code that ran through all frames to make sure the frame I was switching to was present and it is.

**"Basic" frame structure:**

```
<html>
    <head>      
    </head>
    <frameset cols="5,*" border="0" frameborder="no" framespacing="0">
        <frameset rows="145,*" border="0" frameborder="no" framespacing="0">
            <frame name="kalender" src="../calendar/Month.jsp" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" noresize="" scrolling="no">
            <frame name="dagskalender" src="../calendar/NewTimeReg.jsp" marginwidth="10" marginheight="20" noresize="" scrolling="no">
        </frameset>
        <frameset rows="50,*,1" border="0" frameborder="NO" framespacing="0">
            <frameset cols="63,175,*,35" border="0" frameborder="NO" framespacing="0">
                <frame name="dagbund" src="Mail.jsp" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" noresize="" scrolling="NO">
                <frame name="soeg" src="../search/main/Cont.jsp" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" noresize="" scrolling="no">
                <frame name="topbar" src="TopBarMid.jsp" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" noresize="" scrolling="no">
                <frame name="topbarende" src="TopBarRight.jsp" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" noresize="" scrolling="no">
            </frameset>
            <frame name="main" src="../startpage/Fram.jsp?null" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" noresize="">
            <frameset cols="33%,33%,33%,*" border="0" frameborder="NO" framespacing="0">
                <frame name="skjult" src="Blank.jsp" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" noresize="" scrolling="no">
                <frame name="skjult2" src="Blank2.jsp" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" noresize="" scrolling="no">
                <frame name="skjult3" src="Blank3.jsp" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" noresize="" scrolling="no">
                <frame name="AppletLoader" src="" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" noresize="" scrolling="no">
            </frameset>   
        </frameset>
    </frameset>   

</html>
```

I'm trying to switch to the 'main' frame so I first switch to defaultcontent and then try to switch to 'main'

```
getDriver().switchTo().defaultContent();

String SAML = System.getProperty("login.user.saml").toString();
if(SAML.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) // some sites have a extra parent frame
{
    staticlogger.info( "Switching to 'system' frame..." );  
    getDriver().switchTo().frame("system"); //disable step if SAML-login
}       
staticlogger.info( "Switching to 'main' frame..." );
getDriver().switchTo().frame("main");
```

staticlogger.info( "Switching to 'main' frame..." ); is the last that executes so it fails on the getDriver().switchTo().frame("main");

The below code finds the 'main' which means it should be present in the active frame and switchable too because findElements only return from active frame afaik:

```
List<WebElement> ele = getDriver().findElements(By.tagName("frame"));
        for(WebElement el : ele)
        {
            staticlogger.info( "Frame: " + el.getAttribute("name") + " ID: " + el.getAttribute("id"));
            if(el.getAttribute("name").equalsIgnoreCase("main"))
            {
                staticlogger.info( "Switching to 'main' frame..." );    
                getDriver().switchTo().frame(el);
            }

        }
```

Does anyone have an idea or workaround to solve this bug?
Can't post full html of sites as they contain sensitive data/code.

Comment: Does it give the same error when you switch to the frame name ="kalendar"?

Comment: I will test it but don't think so because the sites that have the 'system' parent frame have no problem switching to that frame before switching to the failed 'main'

Comment: I can switch to 'kalender' frame without exception occuring

Comment: Note: in the alternative code at the bottom I still get the same error at getDriver().switchTo().frame(el);

Comment: The frameset hierarchy is...
<frameset ROOT>
 <frameset A>
  <frame name="kalender">
  <frame name="dagskalender">
 </frameset>
 <frameset B>
  <frameset B1>
   <frame name="dagbund">
   <frame name="soeg">
   <frame name="topbar">
   <frame name="topbarende">
  </frameset>
  <frame name="main">
  <frameset B2>
   <frame name="skjult">
   <frame name="skjult2">
   <frame name="skjult3">
   <frame name="AppletLoader">
  </frameset>
 </frameset>
</frameset>
I think you should sequentially switch from "ROOT > B > main" instead of switching to "ROOT > main".

Comment: The problem might be that "main" is 2 levels deep from the ROOT frameset. You might want to switch to the sub-parent frameset as switchTo works on immediate child frames only.

Comment: If I need to switch to framesets first it's just strange that it works for the other frames like kalender which is also within framesets (and works for the same code elsewhere). I don't think a frameset is considered a level as such for selenium. Isn't it just a container?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround

After a lot of trial and error I found the following issues and workarounds:

1. The frame switch exception is actually a StaleElementReferenceException, so the error message "Element belongs to a different frame than the current one - switch to its containing frame to use it" is misleading.
2. If I ignore the exception instead of breaking I can access elements within the frame as I wanted to. So seems it switched to the 'main' frame regardless of the exception
3. After ignoring the exception I got a new error when trying to sendKeys to a element within the frame. The exception is `'Permission denied to access property "__raven__"'`
   From what I could Google it seems this exception can be related to jQuery but I have serenity.jquery.integration=false in serenity.properties.
4. Once again I could continue the test by ignoring the exception and the desired sendKeys value is still entered into the field that caused the exception.
5. After skipping the first `__raven__` error I get another later on (in between the 2 errors are sendKey/findElement usage that does not cause exception) when using findElements which I also can workaround by ignoring error.

Does anyone have any idea why these 2 exceptions occur?

Although the test works now it's a pretty dirty way of doing it, so would still like the issues solved if possible.

New code for "working" frame switch:

```
String SAML = System.getProperty("login.user.saml").toString();

  getDriver().switchTo().defaultContent();

  if(SAML.equalsIgnoreCase("false"))


  {

   staticlogger.info( "Switching to 'system' frame..." ); 

   getDriver().switchTo().frame("system"); //disable step if SAML-login

  }  

  staticlogger.info( "Switching to 'main' frame..." );

  getDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait( 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS );

  try

  {

   getDriver().switchTo().frame("main"); 

  }

  catch ( StaleElementReferenceException ser ) 

  {      

     staticlogger.info( "WARNING: Stale 'main' frame");      

  } 

  catch ( NoSuchFrameException nsf ) 

  {      

     staticlogger.info( "ERROR: No 'main' frame found");             



  } catch ( Exception e ) 

  {

      staticlogger.info( "ERROR: " + e.getMessage() );

  }

  getDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait( DEFAULT_IMPLICIT_WAIT, TimeUnit.SECONDS );


  staticlogger.info( "Done switching to 'main' frame..." );
```

`Workaround for __raven__`

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait( 250, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS );

WebElement we = null;

boolean unfound = true;

int tries = 0;

while ( unfound && tries < 8 ) {

  tries += 1;

  try {

    we = driver.findElement( locator );

    unfound = false; // FOUND IT

  } catch ( StaleElementReferenceException ser ) {      

    staticlogger.info( "Try [" + tries + "] - ERROR: Stale element. " + locator.toString() );

    unfound = true;

  } catch ( NoSuchElementException nse ) {      

    staticlogger.info( "Try [" + tries + "] - ERROR: No such element. " + locator.toString() );

    unfound = true;

  } catch ( Exception e ) {

    staticlogger.info( "Try [" + tries + "] - " + e.getMessage() );

  }

} 

long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

long totalTime = endTime - startTime;

if (we != null)   

 staticlogger.info("Try [" + tries + "] - Found element after " + totalTime + " milliseconds.");

else    

 staticlogger.info("Element NOT found after looking for " + totalTime + " milliseconds.");     

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait( DEFAULT_IMPLICIT_WAIT, TimeUnit.SECONDS );
return we;
```